# Converting Hashtable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I need some help outputting a a hash table to the body of an email message.

```
$computer = "adwte998"
$err = "This is the error"
$td = Get-Date

$table = @{

Workstation = $computer
Error = $err
Time = $td

} 

send-mailmessage -to "email@email.com" -from "Automated Reboot<no-reply@email.com>" -subject "E-Mail HashTable Test" -body ($table | Out-String) -smtpserver smtpserver.email.com
```

The Message body looks like it should if i just returned the $table

I would ideally like to convert the table to a format that looks like a CSV with the proper columns and headers but I don't want to email it as an attachment.

Does anyone know how i can go about doing this?  I would even considering converting it to HTML so it looks nice in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using V3:

```
$computer = "adwte998"
$err = "This is the error"
$td = Get-Date

$table = [ordered]@{
Workstation = $computer
Error = $err
Time = $td
} 

[PSCustomObject]$table | ft -auto | out-string

Workstation Error             Time                 
----------- -----             ----                 
adwte998    This is the error 10/18/2013 1:26:08 PM
```

for HTML:

```
[PSCustomObject]$table | convertto-html
```

Comment: Ok, that solves the formatting of the table if I were to output it on the screen but I wanted to convert it to HTML now so I can use the -BodyAsHtml in Send-MailMessage.  How would I do that?

Comment: Added example for converting to html