# Powershell - help converting hash table to HTML

Tags: html, powershell, hashtable

I have followed an example of creating a hash table and converting it into HTML

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455435/converting-hashtable-in-powershell
```

Here is my example based on this OP's answer:

```
$Summary = @{
Computers=$ADServerCount.count
DMZ=$TotalDMZ.count
No_Ping=$TotalNoPing.count
Reg_Failed=$TotalRegFailed.count
RebootPending=$TotalPendingReboot.count
RebootNotRequired=$TotalNoPatchRequired.count 
}

[PSCustomObject]$Summary | Convertto-HTML -fragment
```

...and here is the result if I were to just run $Summary - just what I expected:

```
Name                           Value                                             
----                           -----                                             
RebootNotRequired              69                                                
DMZ                            10                                                
Computers                      341                                               
Reg_Failed                                                                       
RebootPending                  137                                               
No_Ping                        80
```

However, if I try to convert to HTML, by running [PSCustomObject]$Summary | Convertto-HTML -fragment, I get this without the values from above:

```
<table>
<colgroup>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
</colgroup>
<tr><th>IsReadOnly</th><th>IsFixedSize</th><th>IsSynchronized</th><th>Keys</th>
<th>Values</th><th>SyncRoot</th><th>Count</th></tr>
<tr><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>System.Collections.Hashtable+
KeyCollection</td><td>System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection</td><td>Syst
em.Object</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Please help. Thanks

Here is more of the code - as you can see, there are two further variables that can be converted into an HTML table, $GroupPendingRebootbyOwner and $OlderThan30Days, but the $Summary returns gobbledygook. I have truncated the rest of the code that emails out.

```
$Summary = @{
Computers=$ADServerCount.count
DMZ=$TotalDMZ.count
No_Ping=$TotalNoPing.count
Reg_Failed=$TotalRegFailed.count
RebootPending=$TotalPendingReboot.count
RebootNotRequired=$TotalNoPatchRequired.count 
} 

$ExecSummary = [PSCustomObject]$Summary | Convertto-HTML -fragment

$GroupPendingRebootbyOwner = $AllTeamsFilter | Select Computer, RebootPending, Owner | Where {$_.Rebootpending -match 'True'} | 
Select Computer, Owner | Group Owner | Sort Count -desc | Select Name, Count | Convertto-HTML -fragment

$OlderThan30Days = $AllTeamsFilter | Select Computer, RebootPending, Owner, DaysAgo | 
Where {$_.RebootPending -match 'True' -and $_.DaysAgo -notmatch 'No_Ping' -and $_.DaysAgo -notmatch 'DMZ' -and $_.DaysAgo -notmatch 'Reg_Failed' -and $_.DaysAgo -gt '31'} | 
Select Computer, Owner, DaysAgo | Sort DaysAgo -desc | Convertto-HTML -fragment

$Mailto = "emailaddress"
$EmailFrom = "emailaddress"
$SMTPServer = "smtpserver"
$HTMLmessage = @"
<font color=""black"" face=""Arial"" size=""3"">
<h1 style='font-family:arial;'><b>Windows Updates and Pending Reboot Report</b></h1>
<style type=""text/css"">body{font: .8em ""Lucida Grande"", Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
ol{margin:0 auto;}
table{width:auto;}
thead{}
thead th{font-size:120%;text-align:left;}
th{border-bottom:2px solid rgb(79,129,189);border-top:2px solid rgb(79,129,189);padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;}
tr{padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;border:none;}
#middle{background-color:#900;}
</style>
<body BGCOLOR=""white"">
<p style='font: ""Lucida Grande"", Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'><b>Executive Summary</b><br>
$ExecSummary
<p style='font: ""Lucida Grande"", Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'><b>Pending Reboots by owner ("blank" name = unassigned owner)</b><br>
$GroupPendingRebootbyOwner
<p style='font: ""Lucida Grande"", Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'><b>Last rebooted more than 30 days ago</b><br>
$OlderThan30Days
</body>
"@
```

Comment: What is it you need help with? You've shown how to fixed it yourself, simply convert the hashtable to an object before piping to `ConvertTo-Html`

Comment: I am feeding this into an HTML email body and I am expecting it to have the appropriate values in the hash table, instead I get: "[PSCustomObject]System.Collections.Hashtable "

Comment: Change the last line to `$([PSCustomObject]$Summary) |ConvertTo-Html -Fragment`

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: What version of PowerShell is this?

Comment: Powershell 7 converts hashtable and an object into a html table with each property or key as a column and the data as a row.  It does not follow the 2 column layout we would expect. Presumably this is because its expecting the possibility of an array that it needs to convert, where each obj would be another row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell 2.0, the `[PSCustomObject]$Hashtable` syntax won't work.

Use the [`New-Object` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885.aspx) with the [`-Property` parameter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/12/04/new-object-psobject-property-hashtable/) instead:

```
New-Object psobject -Property $Summary |ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this deserves a bit more of an answer for viewing hashtables in HTML form. If you want to take a hashtable as it appears and place it into HTML for an email or whatever else, you need to enumerate over each entries' keys and values. I believe this advice works for only powershell V3 and above, but I could be wrong. Thus:

```
PS > @{a=2;b=3;}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              2
b                              3
```

Can also be seen as:

```
PS > (@{a=2;b=3;}).GetEnumerator()

Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              2
b                              3
```

And can then be converted via (You may not want fragment, but I use it in HTML often from powershell):

```
PS > (@{a=2;b=3;}).GetEnumerator()| select Key,Value | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>b</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```